# "Examples below" vs "below examples"

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I am always confused with using "below".
My colleague corrected my sentence from:

> Below examples show...

To:

> Examples below show...

Is the first one grammatically wrong? then why?

Comment: Neither one is felicitous, but the second is closer to what might be expected in business or academic writing. Either one is improved by the addition of the definite article: _**The** examples below show..._

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100807/in-the-figure-below-or-in-the-below-figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example

> Below examples show...

is understandable, but lacking since it sounds like *something* is missing, better might be

> Below *are* examples show*ing*...
>   *The* below examples show...

Your second example is better

> Examples below show...
>   *The* examples below show...

since word placement put the emphasis on "examples" and less on "below".
"The" definite article also focuses attention to "examples".

Comment: "The examples below" means "*all* the examples below", while the version without the definite article allows the interpretation "*some* of the examples below".